# Add several images on each element on a sphere using Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

### Here is the spherical structure I was talking about- [Clickhere](https://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable.html)

In this sphere grid, I wish to add several images on each element.
Like, using this code We can transform into various shapes such as Grid,Plane etc. Whatever the shape may be, I want to add different images on each and every element in the grid.

I seriously do not have any clue on this. Could you help me out please?
This is the code I copied and pasted from the three.js webstite:

```js
var table = [
  [ "H", "Hydrogen", "1.00794", 1, 1 ],
  [ "He", "Helium", "4.002602", 18, 1 ],
  [ "Li", "Lithium", "6.941", 1, 2 ],
  [ "Be", "Beryllium", "9.012182", 2, 2 ],
  [ "B", "Boron", "10.811", 13, 2 ],
  [ "C", "Carbon", "12.0107", 14, 2 ],
  [ "N", "Nitrogen", "14.0067", 15, 2 ],
  [ "O", "Oxygen", "15.9994", 16, 2 ],
  [ "F", "Fluorine", "18.9984032", 17, 2 ],
  [ "Ne", "Neon", "20.1797", 18, 2 ],
  [ "Na", "Sodium", "22.98976...", 1, 3 ],
  [ "Mg", "Magnesium", "24.305", 2, 3 ],
  [ "Al", "Aluminium", "26.9815386", 13, 3 ],
  [ "Si", "Silicon", "28.0855", 14, 3 ],
  [ "P", "Phosphorus", "30.973762", 15, 3 ],
  [ "S", "Sulfur", "32.065", 16, 3 ],
  [ "Cl", "Chlorine", "35.453", 17, 3 ],
  [ "Ar", "Argon", "39.948", 18, 3 ],
  [ "K", "Potassium", "39.948", 1, 4 ],
  [ "Ca", "Calcium", "40.078", 2, 4 ],
  [ "Sc", "Scandium", "44.955912", 3, 4 ],
  [ "Ti", "Titanium", "47.867", 4, 4 ],
  [ "V", "Vanadium", "50.9415", 5, 4 ],
  [ "Cr", "Chromium", "51.9961", 6, 4 ],
  [ "Mn", "Manganese", "54.938045", 7, 4 ],
  [ "Fe", "Iron", "55.845", 8, 4 ],
  [ "Co", "Cobalt", "58.933195", 9, 4 ],
  [ "Ni", "Nickel", "58.6934", 10, 4 ],
  [ "Cu", "Copper", "63.546", 11, 4 ],
  [ "Zn", "Zinc", "65.38", 12, 4 ],
  [ "Ga", "Gallium", "69.723", 13, 4 ],
  [ "Ge", "Germanium", "72.63", 14, 4 ],
  [ "As", "Arsenic", "74.9216", 15, 4 ],
  [ "Se", "Selenium", "78.96", 16, 4 ],
  [ "Br", "Bromine", "79.904", 17, 4 ],
  [ "Kr", "Krypton", "83.798", 18, 4 ],
  [ "Rb", "Rubidium", "85.4678", 1, 5 ],
  [ "Sr", "Strontium", "87.62", 2, 5 ],
  [ "Y", "Yttrium", "88.90585", 3, 5 ],
  [ "Zr", "Zirconium", "91.224", 4, 5 ],
  [ "Nb", "Niobium", "92.90628", 5, 5 ],
  [ "Mo", "Molybdenum", "95.96", 6, 5 ],
  [ "Tc", "Technetium", "(98)", 7, 5 ],
  [ "Ru", "Ruthenium", "101.07", 8, 5 ],
  [ "Rh", "Rhodium", "102.9055", 9, 5 ],
  [ "Pd", "Palladium", "106.42", 10, 5 ],
  [ "Ag", "Silver", "107.8682", 11, 5 ],
  [ "Cd", "Cadmium", "112.411", 12, 5 ],
  [ "In", "Indium", "114.818", 13, 5 ],
  [ "Sn", "Tin", "118.71", 14, 5 ],
  [ "Sb", "Antimony", "121.76", 15, 5 ],
  [ "Te", "Tellurium", "127.6", 16, 5 ],
  [ "I", "Iodine", "126.90447", 17, 5 ],
  [ "Xe", "Xenon", "131.293", 18, 5 ],
  [ "Cs", "Caesium", "132.9054", 1, 6 ],
  [ "Ba", "Barium", "132.9054", 2, 6 ],
  [ "La", "Lanthanum", "138.90547", 4, 9 ],
  [ "Ce", "Cerium", "140.116", 5, 9 ],
  [ "Pr", "Praseodymium", "140.90765", 6, 9 ],
  [ "Nd", "Neodymium", "144.242", 7, 9 ],
  [ "Pm", "Promethium", "(145)", 8, 9 ],
  [ "Sm", "Samarium", "150.36", 9, 9 ],
  [ "Eu", "Europium", "151.964", 10, 9 ],
  [ "Gd", "Gadolinium", "157.25", 11, 9 ],
  [ "Tb", "Terbium", "158.92535", 12, 9 ],
  [ "Dy", "Dysprosium", "162.5", 13, 9 ],
  [ "Ho", "Holmium", "164.93032", 14, 9 ],
  [ "Er", "Erbium", "167.259", 15, 9 ],
  [ "Tm", "Thulium", "168.93421", 16, 9 ],
  [ "Yb", "Ytterbium", "173.054", 17, 9 ],
  [ "Lu", "Lutetium", "174.9668", 18, 9 ],
  [ "Hf", "Hafnium", "178.49", 4, 6 ],
  [ "Ta", "Tantalum", "180.94788", 5, 6 ],
  [ "W", "Tungsten", "183.84", 6, 6 ],
  [ "Re", "Rhenium", "186.207", 7, 6 ],
  [ "Os", "Osmium", "190.23", 8, 6 ],
  [ "Ir", "Iridium", "192.217", 9, 6 ],
  [ "Pt", "Platinum", "195.084", 10, 6 ],
  [ "Au", "Gold", "196.966569", 11, 6 ],
  [ "Hg", "Mercury", "200.59", 12, 6 ],
  [ "Tl", "Thallium", "204.3833", 13, 6 ],
  [ "Pb", "Lead", "207.2", 14, 6 ],
  [ "Bi", "Bismuth", "208.9804", 15, 6 ],
  [ "Po", "Polonium", "(209)", 16, 6 ],
  [ "At", "Astatine", "(210)", 17, 6 ],
  [ "Rn", "Radon", "(222)", 18, 6 ],
  [ "Fr", "Francium", "(223)", 1, 7 ],
  [ "Ra", "Radium", "(226)", 2, 7 ],
  [ "Ac", "Actinium", "(227)", 4, 10 ],
  [ "Th", "Thorium", "232.03806", 5, 10 ],
  [ "Pa", "Protactinium", "231.0588", 6, 10 ],
  [ "U", "Uranium", "238.02891", 7, 10 ],
  [ "Np", "Neptunium", "(237)", 8, 10 ],
  [ "Pu", "Plutonium", "(244)", 9, 10 ],
  [ "Am", "Americium", "(243)", 10, 10 ],
  [ "Cm", "Curium", "(247)", 11, 10 ],
  [ "Bk", "Berkelium", "(247)", 12, 10 ],
  [ "Cf", "Californium", "(251)", 13, 10 ],
  [ "Es", "Einstenium", "(252)", 14, 10 ],
  [ "Fm", "Fermium", "(257)", 15, 10 ],
  [ "Md", "Mendelevium", "(258)", 16, 10 ],
  [ "No", "Nobelium", "(259)", 17, 10 ],
  [ "Lr", "Lawrencium", "(262)", 18, 10 ],
  [ "Rf", "Rutherfordium", "(267)", 4, 7 ],
  [ "Db", "Dubnium", "(268)", 5, 7 ],
  [ "Sg", "Seaborgium", "(271)", 6, 7 ],
  [ "Bh", "Bohrium", "(272)", 7, 7 ],
  [ "Hs", "Hassium", "(270)", 8, 7 ],
  [ "Mt", "Meitnerium", "(276)", 9, 7 ],
  [ "Ds", "Darmstadium", "(281)", 10, 7 ],
  [ "Rg", "Roentgenium", "(280)", 11, 7 ],
  [ "Cn", "Copernicium", "(285)", 12, 7 ],
  [ "Uut", "Unutrium", "(284)", 13, 7 ],
  [ "Fl", "Flerovium", "(289)", 14, 7 ],
  [ "Uup", "Ununpentium", "(288)", 15, 7 ],
  [ "Lv", "Livermorium", "(293)", 16, 7 ],
  [ "Uus", "Ununseptium", "(294)", 17, 7 ],
  [ "Uuo", "Ununoctium", "(294)", 18, 7 ]
];

var camera, scene, renderer;
var controls;

var objects = [];
var targets = { table: [], sphere: [], helix: [], grid: [] };

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000 );
  camera.position.z = 1800;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  for ( var i = 0; i < table.length; i ++ ) {

    var item = table[ i ];

    var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
    element.className = 'element';
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + ( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25 ) + ')';

    var number = document.createElement( 'div' );
    number.className = 'number';
    number.textContent = i + 1;
    element.appendChild( number );

    var symbol = document.createElement( 'div' );
    symbol.className = 'symbol';
    symbol.textContent = item[ 0 ];
    element.appendChild( symbol );

    var details = document.createElement( 'div' );
    details.className = 'details';
    details.innerHTML = item[ 1 ] + '<br>' + item[ 2 ];
    element.appendChild( details );

    var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
    object.position.x = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
    object.position.y = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
    object.position.z = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
    scene.add( object );

    objects.push( object );

  }

  // table

  for ( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++ ) {

    var item = table[ i ];

    var object = new THREE.Object3D();
    object.position.x = ( item[ 3 ] * 160 ) - 1540;
    object.position.y = - ( item[ 4 ] * 200 ) + 1100;

    targets.table.push( object );

  }

  // sphere

  var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

  for ( var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

    var phi = Math.acos( -1 + ( 2 * i ) / l );
    var theta = Math.sqrt( l * Math.PI ) * phi;

    var object = new THREE.Object3D();

    object.position.x = 1000 * Math.cos( theta ) * Math.sin( phi );
    object.position.y = 1000 * Math.sin( theta ) * Math.sin( phi );
    object.position.z = 1000 * Math.cos( phi );

    vector.copy( object.position ).multiplyScalar( 2 );

    object.lookAt( vector );

    targets.sphere.push( object );

  }

  // helix

  var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

  for ( var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

    var phi = i * 0.175 + Math.PI;

    var object = new THREE.Object3D();

    object.position.x = 1100 * Math.sin( phi );
    object.position.y = - ( i * 8 ) + 450;
    object.position.z = 1100 * Math.cos( phi );

    vector.copy( object.position );
    vector.x *= 2;
    vector.z *= 2;

    object.lookAt( vector );

    targets.helix.push( object );

  }

  // grid

  for ( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++ ) {

    var object = new THREE.Object3D();

    object.position.x = ( ( i % 5 ) * 400 ) - 800;
    object.position.y = ( - ( Math.floor( i / 5 ) % 5 ) * 400 ) + 800;
    object.position.z = ( Math.floor( i / 25 ) ) * 1000 - 2000;

    targets.grid.push( object );

  }

  //

  renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  //

  controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  controls.rotateSpeed = 0.5;
  controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

  var button = document.getElementById( 'table' );
  button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

    transform( targets.table, 2000 );

  }, false );

  var button = document.getElementById( 'sphere' );
  button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

    transform( targets.sphere, 2000 );

  }, false );

  var button = document.getElementById( 'helix' );
  button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

    transform( targets.helix, 2000 );

  }, false );

  var button = document.getElementById( 'grid' );
  button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

    transform( targets.grid, 2000 );

  }, false );

  transform( targets.table, 5000 );

  //

  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function transform( targets, duration ) {

  TWEEN.removeAll();

  for ( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++ ) {

    var object = objects[ i ];
    var target = targets[ i ];

    new TWEEN.Tween( object.position )
      .to( { x: target.position.x, y: target.position.y, z: target.position.z }, Math.random() * duration + duration )
      .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
      .start();

    new TWEEN.Tween( object.rotation )
      .to( { x: target.rotation.x, y: target.rotation.y, z: target.rotation.z }, Math.random() * duration + duration )
      .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
      .start();

  }

  new TWEEN.Tween( this )
    .to( {}, duration * 2 )
    .onUpdate( render )
    .start();

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  TWEEN.update();
  controls.update();

}

function render() {

  renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#info {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.element {
  width: 140px;
  height: 180px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,255,255,0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgba(127,255,255,0.25);
  cursor: default;
}

.element:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,255,255,0.75);
  border: 1px solid rgba(127,255,255,0.75);
}

  .element .number {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgba(127,255,255,0.75);
  }

  .element .symbol {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    font-weight: bold;

    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px rgba(0,255,255,0.95));
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px rgba(0,255,255,0.95));
    -o-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px rgba(0,255,255,0.95));
    -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px rgba(0,255,255,0.95));
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px rgba(0,255,255,0.95));
  }

  .element .details {
    position: absolute;
    top: 125px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(127,255,255,0.75);
  }

button {
  color: rgba(127,255,255,0.75);
  background: transparent;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(127,255,255,0.75);
  border: 0px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,255,255,0.5);
}
button:active {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0,255,255,0.75);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/tween.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="info"><a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer"href="https://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js css3d</a> - periodic table. <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer"href="https://plus.google.com/113862800338869870683/posts/QcFk5HrWran" target="_blank">info</a>.</div>
<div id="menu">
  <button id="table">TABLE</button>
  <button id="sphere">SPHERE</button>
  <button id="helix">HELIX</button>
  <button id="grid">GRID</button>
</div>
```

Comment: [change the elements to have an `img` tag?](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/dnnzu912/)

Comment: Thanks a lot gman 

Comment: @gman!
I've been trying to add a pop-up window/ dialogues box on click of any element on the sphere, such that the window gives a description about the element. I went through certain articles and learnt that we've to ray caster and image picking. However, I tried a lot and im somehow not able to create a pop up/dialogue box.
Could you help me out on this please?
 
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
     if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                SHOULD I MODIFY THE CODE HERE?
            }